# Dynamic generation of objects in java

Tags: java

```
HashSet<String> outScopeActiveRegionCodeSet=new HashSet<String>();
for (String regionCode : outScopeActiveRegionCodeSet) {
    //code required
}
```

Here i need to create new TransactionLOgDTO objects dynamically insed the loop like below.If there are 3     regioncodes in hashset i need 3 TransactionLOgDTO objects with regionCode appended to name of new object.

```
TransactionLOgDTO regionCode1DTO=new TransactionLOgDTO(); 

}
```

I need something like this to be done...........................

```
for (String regionCode : outScopeActiveRegionCodeSet) { TransactionLOgDTO "regionCode"+DTO=new TransactionLOgDTO(); }
```

Comment: So, what is your question? You know already that you can create new objects using the `new` operator? Objects don't have names; variables do.

Comment: Your question is more like a statement. There is no visible question, if you know how to? then what is restricting you to do so?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to dynamically assign names to variables? As in var1, var2, var3, ..., varN?

Comment: If there are 3 regions inside the outScopeActiveRegionCodeSet , i need to create 3 objects with object name having the regioncode name appended to it like below.                                                               TransactionLOgDTO regionCode2DTO=new TransactionLOgDTO();  TransactionLOgDTO regionCode3DTO=new TransactionLOgDTO();  TransactionLOgDTO regionCode5DTO=new TransactionLOgDTO();

Comment: I guess Lopina you have understood my point

Comment: Am in the process of generating different logs for different regions in my application

Comment: I need something like this to be done........................... for (String regionCode : outScopeActiveRegionCodeSet) {  TransactionLOgDTO "regionCode"+DTO=new TransactionLOgDTO();  }

Comment: No, I don't think you can do that in Java :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using an `ArrayList` instead of putting the index in the variable name:

```
List<TransactionLOgDTO> regionCodeDTOs = new ArrayList<TransactionLOgDTO>();
HashSet<String> outScopeActiveRegionCodeSet=new HashSet<String>();
for (String regionCode : outScopeActiveRegionCodeSet) {
    regionCodeDTOs.add(new TransactionLOgDTO());
}
```

or, since you aren't using the `regionCode` String:

```
List<TransactionLOgDTO> regionCodeDTOs = new ArrayList<TransactionLOgDTO>();
HashSet<String> outScopeActiveRegionCodeSet=new HashSet<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < outScopeActiveRegionCodeSet.size(); i++) {
    regionCodeDTOs.add(new TransactionLOgDTO());
}
```

Then you can access them using:

```
regionCodeDTOs.get(i);
```

**[EDIT]**
If you want to connect the `regionCode` to the `TransactionLogDTO` I would recommend a `Map instead`:

```
Map<String, TransactionLOgDTO> transactionCodeDTOs = new HashMap<String, TransactionLOgDTO>();
HashSet<String> outScopeActiveRegionCodeSet=new HashSet<String>();
for (String regionCode : outScopeActiveRegionCodeSet) {
    transactionCodeDTOs.put(regionCode, new TransactionLOgDTO());
}
```

which are retrieved like:

```
transactionCodeDTOs.get(regionCode);
```

Comment: Keppil...now i have got the objects...but if i want to pass the log objects..i need a name...so how do i add the names to the objects...

Comment: Say if i want to pass the log object for the first region alone how can i do so

Comment: TransactionLogDTO firstRegionLogDTO = transactionCodeDTOs.get(regionCode1);

Comment: THanks Keppil...this is what am able to do also...but my real need is to generate log objects for different regions dynamically ..if 10 regions are there 10 objects should be created dynamically...not manual creation..

Comment: if you have your `regionCode`, you just get the corresponding log object with `transactionCodeDTOs.get(regionCode)`